# javascript form validation doesn't work even though everything seems okay (JS is not disabled in browser)

Tags: javascript, php

I have this form:

```
<form action="../scrapll_m_nonstatic/process/reg/signup_process.php" method="post" name="signUp" onsubmit="return signUpVal()">
            <div id="fieldHolder">
                <input type="text" id="accountFieldFirstName" class="accountField" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
                <input type="text" id="accountFieldLastName" class="accountField" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
                <input type="text" id="accountFieldUsername" class="accountField" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="text" id="accountFieldEmail" class="accountField" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                <input type="password" id="accountFieldPassword" class="accountField" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <div id="subFooter">
                <a data-ftrans="slide reverse" href="index.php" id="signUpButton">Sign In</a>
                <a data-ftrans="slide" href="forgot.php" id="forgotButton">Forgot password</a>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <input type="submit" id="signIn" value="Sign Up" />
        </form>
```

And I have this JS form validation script to check if the forms are empty:

```
function signUpVal()
{
    var firstName = document.forms["signUp"]["firstName"].value;
    var lastName = document.forms["signUp"]["lastName"].value;
    var userName = document.forms["signUp"]["userName"].value;
    var email = document.forms["signUp"]["email"].value;
    var password = document.forms["signUp"]["password"].value;
    if (firstName == null || lastName == "" || lastName == null || lastName == "" ||    userName == null || userName == "" || email == null || email == "" || password == null || password = "")
    {
        alert("Please fill out the form completely");
        return false;
    }
}
```

It doesn't do anything and goes directly to the action PHP script. How can I fix that?

Comment: JavaScript validation is an outdated practice. Just use `<input type="text" required />` instead.

Comment: Yeah, but this is for a mobile website. Do most mobile websites support this attribute?

Comment: Depends on the exact browser, but many do!

Comment: Use your browser’s error console! It would have told you that you are trying to access the value of null or undefined – because `document.forms["signUp"]["userName"]` does _not_ return a form field reference, because you named the form field `username` …

Comment: Geeez, I'm sorry for the waste of time :$ Such a small mistake, the letter "N" -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

1). Name of the user name input does not match in JS code. Fix it to this:

```
<input type="text" name="userName" id="accountFieldUsername" class="accountField" placeholder="Username" />
```

instead of `name="username"`

2). Check your values like this:

```
if (firstName == "" || lastName == "" || userName == "" || email == "" || password == "") {
    alert("Please fill out the form completely");
    return false;
}
```

Also you don't need `== null` checks because form element value cannot be null, it's empty string if left blank.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tn4A6/

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it now, it's all good, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be your problem.

You are using assignment operator `=` instead of comparison operator `==`.

Your if condition should be:

```
 if (firstName == null || lastName == "" || lastName == null || lastName == "" ||    userName == null || userName == "" || email == null || email == "" || password == null || password == "")
    {
        alert("Please fill out the form completely");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Still does the same thing. It looks correct to me too, the last operator was =, I changed it, but still no luck.

Comment: Might be better: `if(!firstName || !lastName || !email || !password)`

Comment: Are checks for `null` necessary? Can form element have no value (as opposed to empty string `""`?

Answer (score 0):

The last "=" (as opposed to "==") in the if (firstName == null .. etc ) statement was seen as a syntax error by IE, so the whole script didn't compile.

Firefox said the same thing, but surprisingly neither of them highlighted it with a popup. Only visible when you click F12 for debugger.

This meant the function signUpVal() didn't compile, so it didn't exist so far as the page was concerned - so the form just submitted.

dfsq's answer provides the rest